# Is it possible to add a white shadow on an SVG image that contains a North arrow and text?

Tags: xml, svg, gis

I have an SVG image of a North arrow that I am using in GIS. The software I am using doesn't allow me to add a 'halo' or any sort of shadow around the North arrow text and components.

It is a requirement that this has a white shadow behind the text, North, East, South and West arrows and halo - although, I can't quite figure this out!

I have tried following tutorials, but not really able to follow how to edit the SVG to this extent! Have never had any issues doing this within QGIS but because this is an Arc component it does not translate!

I did try in R and I got SOMETHING but it would not resize to fit in GIS (I removed the width/height in the notepad and still the same).

What am I doing wrong and is this an easy fix that some kind soul can help me with?

`jsfiddle due to so character limitation` https://jsfiddle.net/ashlosaur/1f5bzk3t/3/

Please help a frustrated person out!

Comment: Please add a minimal example in the question itself. Then you won't be troubled by the character limit. Note that you'd normally create shadows using filters in SVG, there's even an SVGFeDropShadowElement to help you.

Comment: SVG have many layers.  Create a new layer with a white background and drop the SVG image onto the new layer.